# Java word box pattern

Tags: java, string, output, box

I'm trying to create a box pattern that takes a word as an input and prints it out as a box.

I have got the top, bottom, and left-hand side to work but I'm unsure how to do the right-hand side.

More specifically I don't know how to make the system output the word starting from the final letter in the top line.

Does anyone have any ideas?
[image]

Comment: Add code as text not as image

Comment: The "right" part needs to be in same exact loop / line as the "left" part.

Comment: The code should be pasted into the question as text. If it's put in as an image, then for this question to still be valid in the future, the image would still have to be posted. As it is, the question, which is otherwise good, will become useless as soon as your link fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### *java-11*

You can use [`String#repeat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#repeat(int)) to repeat the required number of spaces as shown below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a word: ");
        String word = in.nextLine();
        int len = word.length();

        // Top line
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            System.out.print(word.charAt(i) + " ");
        }

        System.out.println();

        // Left and right letters
        for (int i = 1; i < len - 1; i++) {
            System.out.println(word.charAt(i) + " ".repeat((len - 2) * 2 + 1) + word.charAt(len - i - 1));
        }

        // Bottom line
        for (int i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            System.out.print(word.charAt(i) + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter a word: Hello
H e l l o 
e       l
l       l
l       e
o l l e H
```

**Another sample run:**

```
Enter a word: World
W o r l d 
o       l
r       r
l       o
d l r o W
```

### *Prior to Java-11:*

`String#repeat` was introduced with Java-11. If you are doing it with Java version prior to Java-11, you need to replicate this functionality using a nested loop as shown below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a word: ");
        String word = in.nextLine();
        int len = word.length();

        // Top line
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            System.out.print(word.charAt(i) + " ");
        }

        System.out.println();

        // Left and right letters
        for (int i = 1; i < len - 1; i++) {
            System.out.print(word.charAt(i));
            for (int j = 1; j <= (len - 2) * 2 + 1; j++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.println(word.charAt(len - i - 1));
        }

        // Bottom line
        for (int i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            System.out.print(word.charAt(i) + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When creating the left side of your box, you need to add the letters as well on the right side, you can do that by adding spaces then adding your letter like this:

```
...
for (int index = 1; index + 1 < word.length(); index++)  // left side and right side
{
     System.out.print(word.charAt(index) + " ");
     for (int i = 1; i < word.length() - 1; i++)
     {
          System.out.print("  ");
     }

     System.out.print(word.charAt(word.length() - index - 1) + "\n");
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.format("%" + (length+2) + "s", "")` to print space

Here `length` means length of the entered word.

Whole code:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]){
       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("Enter a word");
       String word = in.next();
       int length = word.length();
       String startWord = word.replace(""," ").trim();
       StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(startWord);
       System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString());
        for (int i = 1; i <length-1 ; i++) {
            System.out.println(word.charAt(i)+String.format("%" + (length+2) + "s", "") +word.charAt(length-1-i));
        }
        System.out.println(stringBuilder.reverse().toString());
    }

}
```